# prawn rails download on open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

I use [prawn-rails](https://github.com/cortiz/prawn-rails).

I have a `show.pdf.prawn` view.

I would like to have an action to download this pdf.

I tried the following:

```
    def download
      send_data(
        show,
        filename: "#{custom_name}.pdf",
        type: 'application/pdf'
      )
    end
```

What it does, is download something called `#{custom_name}.pdf` but I m unable to open it (`falied to load PDF document`).

Having it changed to

```
    def download
      send_file(
        show,
        filename: "#{custom_name}.pdf",
        type: 'application/pdf'
      )
    end
```

I am getting

```
no implicit conversion of true into String
```

Please advice.

Comment: How are you defining custom_name ???

Comment: I will be able to check your solution tomorrow - I already finished work today :)

Comment: My solution was a guess... based on the fact that the prawn-rails gem gives you a view handler, so you shouldn't need to call send_data, or send_file. Just render out the view and set the Content-Disposition. ... I'll be interested to hear if it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work:

```
send_data render_to_string("show"), filename: "#{custom_name}.pdf",
                                    type: 'application/pdf'
```

Also you can use prawnto_2 library:

```
gem "prawnto_2",  require: "prawnto"
```

and then simply render in the controller action:

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf  { 
        prawnto inline:   false,
                filename: "#{custom_name}.pdf",
                prawn:    {} # prawn settings here
    }
  end
end
```

But I'm not sure how this library is currently maintained, however still works with Rails 4.2.x.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def download
  response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + custom_name + '.pdf"'
  render :show, mime_type: Mime::Type["application/pdf"]
end
```

Comment: hey, I've got `undefined method `[]' for Mime::Type:Class` using the suggested solution. Thanks a lot for your input anyway, I really appreciate that!

Comment: Have you tried it without the mine_type --> just render :show ??? If you are using .pdf in the request you probably don't need it. Let me know, and I will update my answer